# Effect of different maturity options in delta-gamma-hedging

Tags: options, portfolio-optimization, hedging, option-strategies

I read about hedging with options and think i got it. However there is a case  am not sure how to handle.

Is there any exception in the delta-gamma-hedging-(calculaton-)technique? - say: solve an set of equations to get the needed stock -and options-amount.

All examples i have seen so far were using options with the same maturity. Will the procedure change if i consider using options with different maturity dates?

Comment: In a Black Scholes world a portfolio of options (some calls, some puts) of different maturities and strikes on the same underlying still has one delta and one gamma, which can be calculated by summing over the deltas and gammas. So you still have the same setup as with a single option situation. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Black-Scholes world a portfolio of options (some calls, some puts) of different maturities and strikes on the same underlying still has one delta and one gamma, which can be calculated by summing over the deltas and gammas. So you still have the same setup as with a single option situation.